# OutOfMemory error in average value of all nodes in tree

Tags: java, tree, out-of-memory, binary-tree

```
public class Node {

  int value;
  List<Node> childNodes;

  Node(int x) {
      value = x;
      childNodes = new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

This is the definition of the node.

```
 public static double averageNodes(Node root) {
      int numofnodes = 0;
      int sum = 0;
      Stack<Node> s = new Stack<Node>();
      s.add(root);
      while (!s.isEmpty()) {
          Node n = s.pop();
          numofnodes++;
          sum += n.value;
            for (Node temp : root.childNodes) {
              s.push(temp);  // Line 1
          }
      }
      return sum / numofnodes;
  }
```

I use the depth first search with stack to traversal the tree. However, when I click run in eclipse, an error message shows up "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" in line 1. Anyone knows to fix the code to avoid this error?

Comment: But I can construct a very simple tree structure in main with only 9 nodes, and that is how I test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not always add the children of the `root` node but the ones of the `n` Node:

```
for (Node temp : n.childNodes) {
    s.push(temp);  // Line 1
}
```

You code causes an infinite loop and infinitely growing stack since you always add the children of the `root` node over and over again.

You take one element out, put all the children in, take on out, put them all in, etc. Just a minor mistake yet pretty severe in what it causes.